# Counting frequency of variables in text data in Fortran

Tags: count, fortran, frequency

I have a data file with information:

```
 x         y       k               !name for the columns to explain

200316157 123 2004121 
200316157 456 2004121 
200316157 789 2004121 
200519776 456 2007234 
200519776 789 2007234 
200812334 123 2010333 
200812334 789 2010333 
200812334 345 2010333 
200812334 567 2010333
```

So each line contains one specific unique piece of information but the rest of the line is information that is repeated. The file will be sorted so the info about each person will always be all in one place.

I want to count the frequency that each unique person (defined by the first column) appears in the data and add that information to the data so it looks like this:

```
     x     y      k        !name for the columns to explain

200316157 123 2004121 3
200316157 456 2004121 3
200316157 789 2004121 3
200519776 456 2007234 2
200519776 789 2007234 2
200812334 123 2010333 4
200812334 789 2010333 4
200812334 345 2010333 4
200812334 567 2010333 4
```

Is this possible? If you have any tips and tricks I would love to hear!

This is my feeble attempt so far:

```
program counting
implicit none 

integer, parameter :: n=40000    !lenght of file

integer, dimension(1:n) :: x, y, k, icount

integer :: i

open (unit=20, file="data.txt", status="old")



do i = 1, n
read (20,2001) x(i), y(i), k(i),
2001 format (i9, 1x, i3, 1x, i7,)
enddo

open (unit=21, file="data2.txt", status="new")   !a new datafile

icount(i) = 0

do
if (x(i) == x(i)) then                      !how can I compare a line to the previous one?????
icount = icount +i
write (21,2021) x(i), y(i), k(i), icount(i)
endif
icount(i) = 0
enddo


2021 format (i9, 1x, i3, 1x, i7, 1x, i1)  !a new datafile

endprogram counting
```

But the only thing this does is:

```
200316157 123 2004121 1
200316157 456 2004121 2
200316157 789 2004121 3
200519776 456 2007234 4
200519776 789 2007234 5
200812334 123 2010333 6
200812334 789 2010333 7
200812334 345 2010333 8
200812334 567 2010333 9
```

I don't know how I can compare line 2 to line 1 and then count the occurrence of each unique person?

*edit

I am also wondering if I can end up with this result:

```
200316157 123 2004121 1
200316157 456 2004121 2
200316157 789 2004121 3
200519776 456 2007234 1
200519776 789 2007234 2
200812334 123 2010333 1
200812334 789 2010333 2
200812334 345 2010333 3
200812334 567 2010333 4
```

Comment: Oh no sorry, they are all meant to be integer! I have now edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem in the following way:

1. user id starts at line `i0`
2. iterate lines until you find a new user id (save last line from previous id in `i1`
3. write out all lines in-between `i0..i1`

Example implementation

```
! a.f90
program counting
  implicit none

  integer, parameter    :: n = 9 ! length of file
  integer               :: i, iounit, i0, i1
  integer, dimension(n) :: x, y, k

  ! read input file
  open (newunit=iounit, file='data.txt', action='read')
  read (iounit, *)
  read (iounit, *)
  do i = 1, n
    read (iounit, *) x(i), y(i), k(i)
  end do
  close (iounit)

  ! compare x array and write out data
  open (newunit=iounit, file='data2.txt', action='write')
  i1 = 0
  do
    ! set i0, i1
    !   i0: line where specific user id starts
    !   i1: line where specific user id ends
    i0 = i1 + 1
    do i = i0, n
      if (x(i) /= x(i0)) exit
      i1 = i
    end do

    do i = i0, i1
      write (iounit, '(i0, 1x, i0, 1x, i0, 1x, i0)') x(i), y(i), k(i), i1-i0+1   ! last column will be total number
      ! write (iounit, '(i0, 1x, i0, 1x, i0, 1x, i0)') x(i), y(i), k(i), i-i0+1 ! last column will increase by 1, resets for new user id
    end do

    if (i1 == n) exit
  end do
  close (iounit)
end program
```

There are two options included on how to write out the last column.
Just uncomment that one line.

For the given input file

```sh
$ cat data.txt
 x         y       k               !name for the columns to explain

200316157 123 2004121
200316157 456 2004121
200316157 789 2004121
200519776 456 2007234
200519776 789 2007234
200812334 123 2010333
200812334 789 2010333
200812334 345 2010333
200812334 567 2010333
```

You will receive the following output

```sh
$ gfortran -g -Wall -fcheck=all a.f90 && ./a.out && cat data2.txt
200316157 123 2004121 3
200316157 456 2004121 3
200316157 789 2004121 3
200519776 456 2007234 2
200519776 789 2007234 2
200812334 123 2010333 4
200812334 789 2010333 4
200812334 345 2010333 4
200812334 567 2010333 4
```

Comment: This is not quite standard Fortran - the x editor descriptor always requires a count, so it should be 1x in the above. That said I think I would use read (iounit, *) x(i), y(i), k(i) as you hardly ever need a format for a read, and * is just more flexible. Write of course is a different story.

Comment: Thank for the help, I really appreciate it. But your output does not count correctly. The first user is supposed to be counted 3x, the second 2x and the last one 4x.

Comment: @Thordis Fixed it (typical offset by one error...)

Comment: @jack Thank you! This is great and now my program works.